# IntelliJIDEA show a type mismatch error with JPA (hibernate H2 dialect) but the code compile

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea, h2, java-11

This is what my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) show me:

[image]

However seems that, when I compile, I don't have any errors! The startime variable is an OffsetDateTime variable.

Why an error is showed inside my IDE?

**UPDATE**

I also tried to restart the IDE and invalidate the cache but nothing happened.

This is my pom.xml file with all the dependecies:

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>...</groupId>
<artifactId>...</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>...</name>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <springfox-version>2.8.0</springfox-version>
    <rest-assured.version>2.9.0</rest-assured.version>
</properties>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--SpringFox dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind-nullable</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Persistence -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Bean Validation API support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Tests -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Could you add your project configuration (dependencies / structure...) ?

Comment: Loos like you are using `?2` and `?3` as a dynamic SQL parameters. Please try adding the regex pattern that would match the `?[number]` format in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Tools | Database | User Parameters -> **Parameter patterns**. Does it help?

Comment: I'm using windows but the path is the same. I added `"?[number["` but nothing change!

Comment: What dialect do you have injected into the string? I do not get this error. Does the application work correctly? Please provide a sample project if problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

`CAST` is a function that allows casting a database value to a specific **database type**:

> Use CAST to convert a value to a specific database type.
>
> Usage
>
> The CAST function is database independent, but requires database
> support.

The cleanest and error free way of handling such a query is to provide an alternative taking as argument the type respectively matching the stored value, which would be `OffsetDateTime` in your case, combined with conversion patterns depending on your business logic:

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Transaction t WHERE t.userId = ?1 
    AND t.startTime BETWEEN ?2 AND ?3")
List<Transaction> getUserTransactionsBetweenTwoDates(final Long userId, 
    final OffsetDateTime begin, final OffsetDateTime end);
```

Otherwise, you can still cast the resulting `OffsetDateTime` value, which is `TIMESTAMP`, to sql type `DATE`:

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Transaction t WHERE t.userId = ?1 AND (CAST(t.startTime AS DATE)) BETWEEN ?2 AND ?3")
List<Transaction> getUserTransactionsBetweenTwoDates(final Long userId, final LocalDate begin, final LocalDate end);
```

Comment: Your first option doesn't work. It doesn't change anything, indeed I have the following compilation error: `Type mismatch: number, date or string is expected`. This is due to the fact that OffsetDateTime is not recognize as a DataBase type. The second option doesn't work either since I have the same compilation error described inside my post.

Comment: How comes the `OffsetDateTime` is supported when storing data and not when querying it? And for the second hint, you can still post the whole stack trace for the error as I can't see how a valid query won't work.

Comment: Sorry @tmarwen, seems that i don't have any compile error if a simply use the first snippet code that I wrote in my post. However my IDE (IntellijIDEA) continues to shows the type mismatch error. I don't know if the conversion is automatically done by hibernate.

Comment: If the error happens to be on the IDE itself, it would be better to add a snapshot with the highlighted error. (You original post conveys that the error happens to be at runtime)